# Redux-forms send values from pristine fields?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Is it possible to make redux-form send even pristine field values with the submit function? I need this because some dropdowns might already have your preferred value when they are rendered, so you don't need to change them. 
This could be solved with adding an extra "blank" option, but this feels like a bad fix. 
Also I have some hidden input fields, with calculated values, and these won't follow either.

Any ideas on how to approach this are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the initial values of for example `select` boxes to be recognized by `react-form` and sent, you have to explicitly define those selections by injecting [the `initialValues` prop](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) into the form component. Unfortunately `redux-form` cannot know which value is automatically selected by the browser.

Hope this helps!